# OpenMP, gfortran and the curse of non-speedup

Tags: multithreading, performance, fortran, openmp

I have a ridiculously parallelizable (in my mind) piece of Fortran code, so I thought I could give OpenMP a try and see if any speedup could be achieved. This is on Windows 10, MinGW64 with gcc 11.2. I have 16 cores and 256 GB of RAM on an Intel Xeon Gold 5122 @ 3.6 GHz.

The code is definitely not a big deal:

```
  start_time = omp_get_wtime() 
  !$omp parallel do default(shared) private(i)
  do i = 1, nF   
    call something(input1, input2(i), input3, input4, output1(i, :), output2(i, :), output3(i, :))   
  end do 
  !$omp end parallel do
  end_time = omp_get_wtime()       
  
  write(*, *) 'Number of threads:', omp_get_max_threads(), ', Elapsed time:', end_time-start_time
```

`nF` is in the order of 8,600. The calculations are completely independent on which `i` index I am looping on, it doesn't matter in which order they are executed. There is no interaction between the inputs or the outputs at iteration `i-1` with their values at iteration `i`. Whatever goes on inside the subroutine `something` is pure calculations, and not that tough either.

Now, I am not expecting magical linear speed improvements, but this is what I get:

```
C:\Users\User\MyProjects\Test>set OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 & test.exe
 Number of threads:           1 , Elapsed time:  0.43099999427795410

C:\Users\User\MyProjects\Test>set OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 & test.exe
 Number of threads:           2 , Elapsed time:  0.75899982452392578

C:\Users\User\MyProjects\Test>set OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 & test.exe
 Number of threads:           4 , Elapsed time:  0.69499993324279785

C:\Users\User\MyProjects\Test>set OMP_NUM_THREADS=8 & test.exe
 Number of threads:           8 , Elapsed time:  0.55299997329711914

C:\Users\User\MyProjects\Test>set OMP_NUM_THREADS=16 & test.exe
 Number of threads:          16 , Elapsed time:  0.57800006866455078
```

Happily, no speed up. And actually a slowdown, no matter how many threads I tell OpenMP to use. It may be that for a code that takes 0.43 seconds to run it's pointless to attempt to use OpenMP, as the thread creation time will always swamp whatever improvement they may bring. It may also be I am misunderstanding how all of this work.

Optimization switches I use to compile the code:

```
-O3 -funroll-loops -march=native -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fopenmp
```

Any explanation is most welcome, and suggestions on modifying my `!$omp` stuff is also welcome.

**EDIT**

I have edited the code by declaring the matrices `outout1`, `output2` etc... as "transposed", so it looks like this:

```
  start_time = omp_get_wtime() 
  !$omp parallel do default(shared) private(i)
  do i = 1, nF   
    call something(input1, input2(i), input3, input4, output1(:, i), output2(:, i), output3(:, i))   
  end do 
  !$omp end parallel do
  end_time = omp_get_wtime()       
  
  write(*, *) 'Number of threads:', omp_get_max_threads(), ', Elapsed time:', end_time-start_time
```

No changes in timings (it's possibly even worse):

```
C:\Users\User\MyProjects\Test>set OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 & test.exe
 Number of threads:           1 , Elapsed time:  0.43000006675720215

C:\Users\User\MyProjects\Test>set OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 & test.exe
 Number of threads:           2 , Elapsed time:  0.63800001144409180

C:\Users\User\MyProjects\Test>set OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 & test.exe
 Number of threads:           4 , Elapsed time:  0.96600008010864258

C:\Users\User\MyProjects\Test>set OMP_NUM_THREADS=8 & test.exe
 Number of threads:           8 , Elapsed time:  0.80500006675720215

C:\Users\User\MyProjects\Test>set OMP_NUM_THREADS=16 & test.exe
 Number of threads:          16 , Elapsed time:  0.75200009346008301
```

Comment: try transposing your `output1`, `output2` and `output3` matrices. Because, ATM the accesses are strided, which implies probably that your problem is memory bound. Just swapping the indexes might do wonders

Comment: Over and above that as the arguments are not unit stride in memory you will probably get temporary arrays created, which *might* require system calls which *may well* be single threaded (but thread safe), so forcing each allocation to wait for the previous one, possibly on another thread, to finish

Comment: @IanBush I suspected something like that but wasn't confident enough to suggest it here (the serialization of the temporary allocations and copies I hadn't thought of though). However, since the transposition of the matrices would make this issue to disappear anyway, I thought proposing it would suffice for this specific case

Comment: Other than saying "transpose your arrays", it's hard to say anything for definite without knowing more about `something`. Modern optimisation is not really about following general rules-of-thumb, but more about profiling specific code, working out what the specific bottlenecks are, and fixing them.

Comment: Also, if your code really "takes 0.43 seconds to run", why are you trying to optimise it? I assume this is a smaller example of a longer code, but things that optimise the small example probably won't optimise the longer code, and vice versa.

Comment: @Gilles : Tried transposing the matrices - no change, it's possibly slightly worse (see the edit)

Comment: My point was: irrespectively of what the subroutine "something" does, can I get N threads to run independently from one another to divide the work on 8600 calls evenly between themselves? The task is obviously embarrassingly parallelizable, but the overhead of creating threads appears to be too much.

Comment: It does not have to be the overhead of *creating* (or scheduling) threads. It can be your memory bandwith. Much more information about *something* is needed, but you probably have to profile yourself. And the results may change with hardware.

Comment: "can I get N threads to run independently from one another to divide the work on 8600 calls evenly between themselves"? Sure, this is what the code you show does. Can your hardware execute it faster? Who knows.